# Angular 2 Change text of HTML element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to change the text of a `html` element.

profile.component.html

```
<div class="col col-sm-12">
  <h2>FirstName LastName</h2>
</div>
```

profile.component.ts

```
changeName():void{
        //Code to change the <h2> element
    }
```

If you could provide code example how to do this, it would be good!.

Comment: I  really think you need to read the quick start tutorial if you are asking a question like this: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I will add that it's bad practice to use capitalized names for variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**interpolation**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----) using the double curly braces `{{ }}` and bind your `FirstName` and `LastName`. Read more about [**template syntax**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-syntax).

Change your html to following:

```
<div class="col col-sm-12">
  <h2>{{ FirstName }} {{ LastName }}</h2>
</div>
```

... and in your `profile.component.ts`:

```
FirstName: string = '';
LastName: string = '';

changeName():void{
    this.FirstName = 'New First Name';
    this.LastName = 'New Last Name';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:-At html file (profile.component.html)

```
<div class="col col-sm-12">
  <h2 *ngIf="data==null; else elseBlock" >FirstName LastName</h2>
<ng-template #elseBlock><h2  [innerHTML] = "data"></h2></ng-template>
</div>
```

Step 2: At ts file (profile.component.ts)

```
public data:any;
changeName():void{
       this.data="Your Data";
    }
```